# how to process $\max(x,0)$ in optimization problems

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, vectors, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

my objective contains the forms of $\max(x,0)$ which can be written as
{
    \begin{align}
 \mathop{\max}\limits_{{\bf{P}},\theta}\quad&R^{sec}_{tot}\\
 \textrm{s.t.} \quad\:
 &C_{c,e} \le R_{c},\\
 &\text{tr}\left({\bf{P}}{{\bf{P}}^H}\right) \le {P_T},
 \end{align}

where $R_c^{\sec } = {[{R_c} - {C_{c,e}}]^ + }$, $R_{p,k}^{\sec } = {[{R_{p,k}} - {C_{k,e}}]^ + }$,$R_{c}=\min(R_{c,1},R_{c,2})$, $ k=1,2$.and I converted it to
{
    \begin{align}
 \mathop{\max}\limits_{\boldsymbol{P},\theta,{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}_{p},{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}_{c}} & \mathop{\min} \{ \alpha_{c,1},\alpha_{c,2}\} +\sum\nolimits_{k} \left(\alpha_{p,k}-\alpha_{k,e}\right)-\alpha_{c,e}\\
 \textrm{s.t.} \quad\:
 &R_{p,k} \ge \alpha_{p,k},\\
 &R_{c,k} \ge \alpha_{c,k},\\
 &C_{k,e} \le \alpha_{k,e},\\
 &C_{c,e} \le \alpha_{c,e},\\
 &\alpha_{c,e} \le \alpha_{c,1},\\  &\alpha_{c,e} \le \alpha_{c,2},\\
 &\text{tr}\left({\bf{P}}{{\bf{P}}^H}\right) \le {P_T},
 \end{align}
via introducing some non-negative vector, and compute $\max(\min(\alpha_{c,1},\alpha_{c,2}),0)+\max(\alpha_{p,1}-\alpha_{1,e},0)+\max(\alpha_{p,1}-\alpha_{1,e},0)$. But from the simulation, I find the result is not my expectation. Then, what I should do to convert the problem?

Comment: What is a function of $\theta$ here? Basically, can you list all the decision variables of the problem properly underneath the $\max$ in the first problem? Also, I suggest removing letters from the subscripts if not really needed. Simplify and clarify the problem as much as possible, please!

Comment: sorry for I don't describe the problem clearly. $ \theta $ is a variable and it satisfies $0<= \theta <=1$, $R_{tot}^{sec}=R_c^{sec}+R_{p,1}^{sec}+R_{p,1}^{sec}$, and for the first constraint in the first problem, the $[]^{+}$ of $ R_c^{sec}$ can be deleted.

Comment: Actually, it is a question: $\max \quad (x+\max(y,0)+\max(z,0))$, the object is non-convex, how should i do to convert it?

Comment: After receiving answers to your question, it is a good idea to respond or to accept the given answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it eventually is $$\max_{x\in \mathcal F_1,y\in \mathcal F_2,z\in \mathcal F_3} \quad x+\max(y,0)+\max(z,0),$$ 
then you can equivalently rewrite it as $$\max_{x\in \mathcal F_1,y\in \mathcal F_2,z\in \mathcal F_3,\gamma_1,\gamma_2} \quad x+\gamma_1+\gamma_2 \quad \text{ subject to } \quad \max(y,0)\ge \gamma_1 \text { and } \max(z,0)\ge \gamma_2.$$
The latter problem is equivalent to
$$\max_{x\in \mathcal F_1,y\in \mathcal F_2,z\in \mathcal F_3, \gamma_1,\gamma_2} \quad x+\gamma_1+\gamma_2 \quad \text{ subject to } \quad y+|y|\ge 2\gamma_1 \text { and } z+|z|\ge 2\gamma_2.$$

So, we need to solve four problems where we play with the sign of $y$ and $z$ and eventually, take the largest value as the optimal value (I do not know an elegant way to remove $|.|$ from the constraints).

By the way, note that in general, $$\max_{x\in \mathbb R^n} \, f(x)$$ is equivalent to $$\max_{x\in \mathbb R^n,t\in \mathbb R} t \quad \text{ subject to } \quad f(x)\ge t.$$ and $\max(z,0)=(z+|z|)/2$. 
Thus, you can always assume the objective function is linear.